# Google Maps Cache Custom Map Images

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have made a custom map using the Google map API v.3. I am trying to reduce the blank squares that you see when panning or zooming by caching the images.

I am currently looping through all the images in JavaScript and loading them into image object before I load the map, but this hasn't really improved it at all. It seems when ever the map loads it still makes its own calls for those images and it is only after visiting that part of the map does the map run smoothly without any blank squares.

Does anyone know how to improve the performance of the image loading for Google maps?

Comment: Interesting question, but I don't think it's good. Do you have any idea how large it is to preload to everything into the cache? By just browsing the gmap alone, I used up to 1000 requests and 10Mb of data transfered. Have you consider your clients could have slow internet connection?

Comment: But I have made a custom map from a custom image which is not as big as Google's map of the Earth, so there will be a limit to how much I have to cache.